# Any example for ResolveScriptReference?

Tags: asp.net

Cannot find any example on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example in the [ScriptReferenceEventArgs docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreferenceeventargs.aspx)

Off the top of my head, you may use it to append the version to the script path so the client updates any stale cached javascript when you release a new version, like this:

```
ScriptManager1_ResolveScriptReference(object sender, ScriptReferenceEventArgs e)
{
    e.Script.Path += "?v=" + MyAppVersion;
}
```

SO uses this technique as well (though not the function, or webforms), look at the source of this page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=6638">
```